# How to get zipcode - timezone data using python?

Tags: python, datetime, localization

I am looking for a python package which can provide functionality like the following -

```
timezone = foo.gettimezoneinfo(zipcode)
date_time = foo.convert_time(datetime object, zipcode)
```

Is there any such package available? If not, how can I implement one? Any zipcode - timezone database is available to use?

I need to use this with US and Canada areacodes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [pyzipcode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyzipcode). It was updated on 2010-09-06 so I would assume that is pretty accurate. I have never used it but, it looks pretty simplistic. If you run into issues; I can test it out and post some source code.

The **Basic Usage** section has some code that I believe will satisfy your query.

Comment: how do I get the time for a zipcode using pyzipcode?

Comment: Does not satisfy request.